# How do I make a border-box get bigger when I hover over something on top of it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make 4 small boxes get bigger whenever you hover over the box on top of them as an aesthetic style.

I have tried looking for examples online and on StackOverflow but every example I tried did not work either because it was in JavaScript and I just didn't understand it or it was in J Query and I'm not using J Query (I'm not certain if I should). This is what I'm trying to get. https://imgur.com/a/jy4ozCe

I have all the HTML and CSS done except I can't seem to make the function work. I am new to React and Javascript and I'm a bit lost at the moment.

I tried

JS

```
function animation(color) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('animated-box').style.backgroundColor = 'color';
}
```

HTML

```
 <div className="hp-left">
        <div className="home-card-top-left">
            <iframe title="JSX" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rUvUKWbyMgM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen />
            <div className="animated-box"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="home-card-bottom-left" onmouseover={animation('red')} onmouseout={animation('white')}>
            <a href="https://www.gofundme.com/gamehubgg?fbclid=IwAR1QApuq8jTeihAAcx8Y_1i23PSDLXEo9nDocQvUHuOMIxVLMK6x2pqcRK0">
            <img
              className="haloimg"
              src={
                "https://zach-miller.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/its-giveaway-time.jpg"
              }
              width="50%"
              height="100%"
              alt="Halo Pic"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

which was an answer someone gave on StackOverflow but that gives me

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

This is just a snippet of the "div" I want to hover over and the box.

I want to hover over the bigger section and make the small box grow until it is encompassing the big box. I tried to do this in CSS but it wouldn't work there either because it is behind the div. I want to do it in JS or JSX anyways.

Comment: But do you have element with clase name 'animated-box'? I don't see any

Comment: Try getElementsByClassName('haloimg')

Comment: Sorry guys I was trying to condense the code because it looked confusing but I cut out the box part from the first 'home-card-top-left'. Sorry!

Comment: I put the 'animated-box' back.

Comment: When I cut it out, I cut it out of the StackOverflow. It was still in my code in case that was confusing. I still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `state` and `handleMouseHover` with:

```
<div
  onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
  onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
>
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/j4x14q6q35

For `onhover style` you can user `transform: scale`.

Answer (score 2):

If I right understand what you want, is it?
If i wrong, please give more details, with mo examples!

```css
.box-hover {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box-hover:hover ~ * {
  border-width: 10px;
}

.box-border {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class='box-hover'>hover on me</div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is close but I want to do it in JSX and not using css:hover

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i don't know jsx, here vanilla js )))

```js
let
  boxHover = document.querySelector('.box-hover'),
  boxBorder = document.querySelectorAll('.box-border');

boxHover.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < boxBorder.length; i++) {
    boxBorder[i].style.borderWidth = '10px'
  }
})
```

```css
.box-hover {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box-border {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class='box-hover'>hover on me</div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
<div class='box-border'></div>
```